# how to declare a dynamic array using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby

i am trying to declare a dynamic array like below.

<% Product_in_Stock_array = [] %>

but it is not working giving syntax error.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: @SCM : What is a **dynamic** array? Your code simply produces a Ruby `Array`, **constant** which is the empty array. For experimenting with the syntax, don't do it in templates, but  do it first inside `irb`. Constants are nor really constant in Ruby, but you get an error message if you try to reassign it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to be a bit more specific.

The code you have is most likely an `erb` template file.
This is actually a valid `erb` template

```
ERB.new('<% Product_in_Stock_array = [] %>').result
```

Your syntax error has to be somewhere else.

Additionally you most likely want to create a variable not a constant. In Ruby names starting with capital letter are constants (written in `UpperCamelCase` or `UPPER_CASE` most often), normal variables are written in `camel_case`.